# jQuery UI Dialogue - IE 7 Error

Tags: jquery-ui

I have some jQuery code contributed by another member of the stack overflow community - it works fine in Crome and Firefox but errors and wont work in IE 7.

The code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
            $("#MyDialog").dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                width:600,
                height:500,
                resizable:false,
                draggable: false,
                modal:true,
            }); < -- Errors Here
        });
```

The error is: Expected Identifier, String or Number.

Many Thanks,
JPH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
            $("#MyDialog").dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                width:600,
                height:500,
                resizable:false,
                draggable: false,
                modal:true,
            }); < -- Errors Here
        });
```

Remove the last , (e.g. after modal:true) and this example works with IE7.